# An interesting Definite Integration Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I solve this
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{\displaystyle2\pi x}-1}{e^{\displaystyle2\pi x}+1}\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{x}{N^2+x^2} \Bigg)dx $$
It is possible to prove that its value can be written as a fraction a/b, where a and b are positive integers.
Where N is a positive integer.

Comment: *"Yes, we can !"*. Could you at least explain why it looks interesting ? By the way, *Welcome to the site !*

Comment: because it can be expressed as a/b. :P

Comment: I'm stuck at this, I need some approach.

Comment: This is a problem from [CodeChef](https://www.codechef.com/DEC20B/problems/CALCULUS).